# Capturing private ip of an ansible created ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have a playbook to provision an EC2 instance using ansible. The task I paste here minus authentication information:

```
amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
  region: "{{ region }}"
  state: running
  wait: true
  count: 1
  image_id: "{{ image_id }}"
  instance_type: t2.mini
  name: new-ec2-instance
register: ec2
```

I need to access the private ip of the new instance. I have inspected the JSON contained in the ec2 variable and I know the private ip of an instance can be obtained at:

`ec2.instances[0].network_interfaces[0].private_ip_address`

However, the problem I am running into is that the "instances" list contains more then just the newly created ec2. It seems to contain all the instances that I have created. Therefore I cannot seem to reliably use the 0 index.

Can anyone say how to reliably get the private IP of the newly created instnace?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data structure `ec2`, means output of the registered variable `ec2`?

Comment: i think i may have found problem. The name of the instance should be unique each time. Else the json returned seems to have all instances with the same name as the newly created